# AWS DMS transformation rules not adding Column on Target Postgres DB

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, dms

I have been trying to add a new column to a target Postgres DB using the transformation rule. I have set up the DMS with CDC.

DMS is able to sync all changes from the table but not performing ADD/Modify column operation.

Any comments on the above?  What I am missing here?

Comment: Can you share your json mapping rules?